# MySQL how to populate query columns based on a condition?

Tags: mysql

I have a query preparing some customer data for a CSV export:

```
SELECT cu.*, 
ct1.CON_FirstName AS billing_FirstName , ct1.CON_MiddleI AS billing_MiddleI , ct1.CON_LastName AS billing_LastName , ct1.CON_Address1 AS billing_CON_Address1 , ct1.CON_Address2 AS billing_CON_Address2 , ct1.CON_City AS billing_CON_City , ct1.CON_State AS billing_CON_State , ct1.CON_Province AS billing_Province , ct1.CON_Country AS billing_Country , ct1.CON_Zip AS billing_Zip , ct1.CON_Phone1 AS billing_Phone1 , ct1.CON_Phone2 AS billing_Phone2 , ct1.CON_Text AS billing_Text , ct1.CON_FriendlyName AS billing_FriendlyName , ct1.CON_Email AS billing_Email,
ct2.CON_FirstName AS shipping_FirstName , ct2.CON_MiddleI AS shipping_MiddleI , ct2.CON_LastName AS shipping_LastName , ct2.CON_Address1 AS shipping_CON_Address1 , ct2.CON_Address2 AS shipping_CON_Address2 , ct2.CON_City AS shipping_CON_City , ct2.CON_State AS shipping_CON_State , ct2.CON_Province AS shipping_Province , ct2.CON_Country AS shipping_Country , ct2.CON_Zip AS shipping_Zip , ct2.CON_Phone1 AS shipping_Phone1 , ct2.CON_Phone2 AS shipping_Phone2 , ct2.CON_Text AS shipping_Text , ct2.CON_FriendlyName AS shipping_FriendlyName , ct2.CON_Email AS shipping_Email

FROM CUSTOMERS cu 

LEFT JOIN  CONTACT ct1 ON ct1.CON_CustomerID = cu.CU_CustomerID AND ct1.CON_Type = 1

LEFT JOIN  CONTACT ct2 ON ct2.CON_CustomerID = cu.CU_CustomerID AND ct2.CON_Type = 2

GROUP BY cu.CU_CustomerID

ORDER BY cu.CU_CustCatId DESC
```

My problem is that there is a third CON_Type value of "3" which means the contact information is both billing and shipping. i.e. some users have two entries in the CONTACT table and others [whose shipping and billing are the same] only have one entry.

How do I populate both the shipping and billing columns for records that only have the CON_Type = 3?

Comment: What do you mean "only have con_type = 3" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested it but I'd assume:

```
LEFT JOIN  CONTACT ct1 ON ct1.CON_CustomerID = cu.CU_CustomerID AND (ct1.CON_Type = 1 OR ct1.CON_Type = 3)

LEFT JOIN  CONTACT ct2 ON ct2.CON_CustomerID = cu.CU_CustomerID AND (ct2.CON_Type = 2 OR ct2.CON_Type = 3)
```

Comment: Sometimes the simplest answer is just sitting right in front of you eh?

Comment: @SeanKimball, it happens.  Gordon's IN suggestion is pretty useful too, especially if you have more than 2 values for the same column.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `in` in the `on` clause, if I understand correctly:

The `from` clause would look like:

```
FROM CUSTOMERS cu LEFT JOIN 
     CONTACT ct1
     ON ct1.CON_CustomerID = cu.CU_CustomerID AND ct1.CON_Type IN (1, 3) LEFT JOIN 
     CONTACT ct2
     ON ct2.CON_CustomerID = cu.CU_CustomerID AND ct2.CON_Type IN (2, 3)
```

If you want to exclude types 1 and 2 (and other types), then you can filter them out:

```
FROM CUSTOMERS cu LEFT JOIN 
     CONTACT ct1
     ON ct1.CON_CustomerID = cu.CU_CustomerID AND ct1.CON_Type = 3 LEFT JOIN 
     CONTACT ct2
     ON ct2.CON_CustomerID = cu.CU_CustomerID AND ct2.CON_Type = 3
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM CUSTOMERS cu2
                  WHERE cu2.CU_CustomerID = cu.CU_CustomerID and
                        cu2.CON_Type <> 3
                 )
```